# How to build a 3D model of a building without height attributes?

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap

I have a building from .osm file:

```
 <way id="85272711" visible="true" version="6" changeset="82733303" timestamp="2020-03-27T20:56:51Z" user="Sakhabudinov" uid="8771823">
  <nd ref="2184292695"/>
  <nd ref="2184292696"/>
  <nd ref="2184292699"/>
  <nd ref="2184292706"/>
  <nd ref="988782834"/>
  <nd ref="988782835"/>
  <nd ref="2184292676"/>
  <nd ref="2184292678"/>
  <nd ref="7335937480"/>
  <nd ref="3780725364"/>
  <nd ref="3780725360"/>
  <nd ref="988782837"/>
  <nd ref="2184292701"/>
  <nd ref="2184292703"/>
  <nd ref="2184292695"/>
  <tag k="building" v="industrial"/>
  <tag k="roof:material" v="metal"/>
  <tag k="roof:shape" v="hipped"/>
 </way>
```

It doesn't have height or levels attributes.
How do I build its 3d model in QGIS?

Answer (score 3):

You can type a fixed value for "Extrusion" option in "Layer Styling (F7) > 3D View" tab.

[image]

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't work for me. There are more than four nodes in the building, and I assume that the remaining nodes are on the top face of the building. I would like to build a model for these nodes

Comment: Please add this clarification to the question body and what you mean by "building a model for these nodes".